Order drawing layer and categories in QGIS
I have many layers in a view in QGIS with many different symbologies in each one.

I need that one of those categories (RES) in a layer that is below (RedTransporte_pol), can be represented on top of the rest of the layers. The rest of the categories of that layer must be represented in that position and not on top.
We have tried to solve it with the symbol level tools, but it seems to me that this tool is useful to represent the order of different features on the same layer and not on different ones.
It is not possible to include elements from one layer in another, because the model data is very strict, so I need to change just the symbology question. How can I do this?

Right-click on layer RedTransporte_pol and select "duplicate layer". Drag the duplicated layer to the top of the layer list, then turn off very uncheck every entry except RES.

Thank you for your answer. I would prefer not to duplicate the layer. The Qgis project is the final result for a client and I would prefer to display it correctly.
